# Dynamically selecting variables based upon a random number generator's results

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, scope, eval

Still learning programming and I'm trying to figure out a way to dynamically select a variable based upon a random number generator's results, so it will be different each time. After pouring through the MDN documentation, the only thing I've found that will let me concatenate a prefix with another variable's value to form a variable's name to select is eval(), but MDN **specifically** says it has a major security risk, so it's best to not use it. Does anyone know a safe alternative (besides a long switch case or if statement) to eval() that will do the same job for this particular task? For reference, the code with eval() would look like this:

```
const val0 = 'a';
const val1 = 'b';
const val2 = 'c';
const val3 = 'd';
const val4 = 'e';

const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

const concat = eval("val" + randNum);
console.log(concat);
```

If there is no other function that can accomplish this, is there any way to remove the security risk in this particular case? Maybe if `eval("val" + randNum);` was put into an IIFE since it's lexical scope would then be enclosed? Sorry if this seems elementary, but I'm still in school and learning. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array to store all those variable values like`values = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']` and can get random from this array `values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)]`.